# How to programmatically mark and then select a subset of input cells?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I'm developing a package that needs to exert significant control over a notebook while a user interacts with it. One specific thing that it needs to do, programmatically, is to select a specific subset of Input cells in order to do things to them -- set cell options, check their contents, etc. I can't figure out how to do this.

One solution that occurred to me is to apply a `CellTag` to those Input cells, so that I can select them with `NotebookFind` or `NotebookLocate`. The problem with this strategy is that whenever any of these Input cells are evaluated, the corresponding Output cells inherit the tag. So, my `NotebookFind` will select both the Input cells I want and these new Output cells I don't. I could instead have `NotebookFind` locate all Input cells, but as far as I can tell there's no way to say "Find all cells of type Input with tag XXX." `NotebookFind` won't accept multiple search criteria, and can't be limited to currently-selected cells.

Another potential solution is to create a new kind of cell that functions just like an Input cell, and make all the cells I want to find be of this cell style. Unfortunately, I haven't had any luck "subclassing" the Input cell style this way, or finding any information about how to do that. It seems that if I want a cell to behave like an Input cell, it has to *be* an Input cell.

Can anyone wiser than I suggest a way to designate, and later to programmatically select, a subset of Input cells?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a special cell attribute called `CellID`. I would suggest using this instead of cell tags to avoid the problem that you mentioned with cell tags being inherited.

Here's an example of how `Select` can be used to retrieve a cell with a specific cell ID:

```
nb = CreateWindow[];

cells = <|
   "name" -> RandomInteger[10^6],
   "status" -> RandomInteger[10^6]
   |>;
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["John Doe", "Subsection", CellID -> cells["name"]]];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["Employed", "Text", CellID -> cells["status"]]];

getCell[id_] := SelectFirst[Cells[nb], CurrentValue[#, "CellID"] == id &]

setContent[id_, content_] := NotebookWrite[
  getCell[id],
  Cell[content, "Text", CellID -> id]
  ]
```

You should now have a notebook in front of you with a name and an employment status. Example usage of `setContent`:

```
setContent[cells["status"], "It's complicated"]
```

Comment: So I can assign the same `CellID` to more than one cell? And then select them all, by using `Select` rather than `SelectFirst`?

Comment: @ibeatty Actually I would probably give each cell a unique ID and group IDs together in a list, as a matter of sound practice, in case you need to address them individually later on. But giving them the same ID would work too.

Comment: @Pickett It seems that the same in principle can be achieved with `CellTags`. What is the advantages of `CellID` as compared to `CellTags`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov ibeatty mentioned in his question that output cells inherit cell tags, so you'll end up with cells that have the same ID even though they shouldn't. This is not the case with `CellID`.

Comment: This solution is less than ideal, because CellID must be manipulated programmatically whereas CellTags and cell styles can be set in the front end... but it seems to be the only possibility. So, I'm accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cells that satisfy multiple criteria by using [`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cells). For example:

```
CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[x^2, "Input", CellTags->"tag"];
CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[x, "Input", CellTags->"tag"];
CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[x^2, "Output", CellTags->"tag"];

cells = Cells[CellTags->"tag", CellStyle->"Input"]
```

> x^2
>
> x
>
> x^2
>
> {CellObject[84705], CellObject[84737]}

will return a list of all cells that have the [`CellTags`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellTags) "tag" and are "[`Input`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Input)" cells. You can use the output in functions like [`NotebookRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookRead), [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue), [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions), etc:

```
NotebookRead[cells]
CurrentValue[cells, CellChangeTimes]
SetOptions[#, CellLabel->"FOO"]& /@ cells
```

> {Cell[BoxData[SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]], "Input", GeneratedCell -> True, 
>     CellAutoOverwrite -> True, CellChangeTimes -> {3.71269*10^9}, 
>     CellTags -> "tag"], 
>    Cell[BoxData["x"], "Input", GeneratedCell -> True, CellAutoOverwrite -> True,
>      CellChangeTimes -> {3.71269*10^9}, CellTags -> "tag"]}
>
> {{3.71269*10^9}, {3.71269*10^9}}
>
> {Null, Null}