# How to close all tagged input cells without closing their output cells?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I have tagged certain Input cells I want to be closed during a presentation.  I close them as follows:

```
Do[CurrentValue[cell, CellOpen] = False,
 {cell, Cells[CellTags -> {"noclass"}]}
]
```

The problem: the associated Output cells also closed, even though they are not tagged. (I assume the `CellOpen` setting is being inherited?)  How can I keep these Output cells open (or reopen them without opening the tagged Input cells)?

**Edit:**

The comments say it is the tag that is inherited, not `CellOpen`.  One answer suggests on this basis to try

```
Do[CurrentValue[cell, CellOpen] = False, {cell, 
  Cells[CellStyle -> {"Input"}, CellTags -> {"noclass"}]}]
```

I had already tried this unsuccessfully. I had even followed up with

```
Do[CurrentValue[cell, CellOpen] = True, {cell, 
  Cells[CellStyle -> {"Output"}, CellTags -> {"noclass"}]}]
```

However, in fact if I run these in isolation they sometimes work.  (That sometimes is a warning; I have not been able to pin down.)  Here is what appears to have created a problem for me.

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectAll"]
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]
```

If I execute these front-end tokens, tagged input cells seem to be grouped with their output.  There then appears to be no way to open the output without opening the input ... that is, I have not found one.

**Edit #2:**

Here is how I currently understand my situation, after the helpful comments below.

When I select everything and close all groups, this naturally closes the input-output groups.  When I subsequently execute the notebook, it leaves all groups closed *except* the input-output groups, which change to an open state. (Perhaps they are even considered to be "new" cell groups, so they get a default state of open?)

In contrast, suppose I close all groups but do not subsequently evaluate the input cells, so the input-output groups remain in a closed state.  The display for a closed input-output group is the input cell.  (Right?)  So when the input cell (of a closed input-output group) is in a closed state, nothing displays, even if the output is in an open state.  I cannot change the display state of an input-output group simply by changing the display state of its cells.

If this is all correct, we arrive to my question: how can I change the display state (to open) of all input-output groups in a notebook, without opening any other groups and without changing the `CellOpen` state of the input cells?  I would like to do something like

```
Do[CurrentValue[cell,GroupOpen]=True,
   {cell,Cells[CellStyle->{"Input"}]}]
```

but that `GroupOpen` property does not appear to exist.  (Or am I just not finding it under another name?)  I would also be happy to select all input-output groups and toggle the `"OpenCloseGroup"`, but I do not see how to make that selection.

**Edit #3:**

While not exactly what I was searching for, the following gets me where I was trying to go:

```
(* start with initial state of all groups open *)
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectAll"]
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionOpenAllGroups"]
(* use tag to choose input cells to keep invisible *)
testInputs = Cells[CellStyle -> {"Input"}, 
  CellTags -> {"test"}];  (* input cells to keep invisible *)
Do[CurrentValue[cell, CellOpen] = False, {cell, 
  testInputs}] ;  (* close them (i.e., invisible *)
(* prepare notebook for presentation by closing sections *)
cells2close = Cells[CellStyle -> {"Section", "Subsection", "Subsubsection"}]
SelectionMove[#, All, Cell]; FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]; & /@ cells2close;
```

The only thing missing is that I specify which groups to close instead of closing all except the input-output groups.

Comment: It's not CellOpen what is inherited but CellTags.

Comment: Please provide an example Notebook with the problem for testing.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Not sure how best to do that.  Does [this](https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/misc/problem20150829.nb) work?

Comment: @Alan I have checked your Notebook with *Mathematica* 10.2 on Win7 x64 and everything works as expected. The Output cell which is grouped with closed Input cell can be seen by double-clicking the right frame of the cell group which appears as arrow. Which version and on what OS do you use?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You say everything works as "expected".  1. Did everything work as I described in the Notebook.  (Because what I carefully described cannot I think be considered "expected".)  2. How can I *programmatically* open those output cells, so that Section 1 behaves just like it does when I evaluate the whole notebook?  (Btw, I am on the same Mma version and OS.)  Thanks!

Comment: @Alan 1. Yes, everything works as you described and it is the expected behavior. 2. Please see the "UPDATE" section in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly specify that only `"Input"` `Cell`s should be closed:

```
Do[CurrentValue[cell, CellOpen] = False,
 {cell, Cells[CellStyle -> {"Input"}, CellTags -> {"noclass"}]}
]
```

As [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) notes [in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92547/how-to-close-all-tagged-input-cells-winout-closing-their-output-cells/92572#comment251722_92547), it is `CellTags` what is inherited by generated output `Cell`. This issue recently raised in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90142/280). If the inheritance is not desirable you can [use `CellID`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91145/280) instead of `CellTags`.

---

### UPDATE

From the discussion in the comments I see your confusion: you misinterpret the meaning of the option `CellOpen`. This option is NOT related to opening or closing of `Cell` groups, it just hides the content of a `Cell` when is set to `False` for that `Cell`.

In your example Notebook you evaluate `FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]`, this piece of code collapses all the `Cell` groups within the selection but does not close the `Cell`s in the meaning of the option `CellOpen`. Similarly, you cannot open a `Cell` group by setting the option `CellOpen` for a `Cell` inside of that group! This is the reason why the code `Do[CurrentValue[cell, CellOpen] = True, {cell, Cells[]}]` does not open any group. For opening a group you have to explicitly open it. One way to do the latter is to select the group and then evaluate `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]`.

For example, the following toggles the state of the last `Cell` group in your example Notebook:

```
cellObj = First@Cells[CellStyle -> {"Input"}, CellTags -> {"test"}];
SelectionMove[cellObj, All, Cell];
FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]
```

You also can play with that group in another way, toggling the visibility of the Input `Cell`:

```
cellObj = First@Cells[CellStyle -> {"Output"}, CellTags -> {"test"}];
SelectionMove[cellObj, All, Cell];
FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]
```

The following closes all the Input-Output groups in the Notebook:

```
cellObjs = Cells[CellStyle -> {"Input"}]
SelectionMove[#, All, Cell]; FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]; & /@ cellObjs;
```

This will open them:

```
cellObjs = Cells[CellStyle -> {"Output"}];
SelectionMove[#, All, Cell]; FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionOpenAllGroups"]; & /@ 
  cellObjs;
```

Toggle the visibility of the Input `Cell`s in the Input-Output groups:

```
cellObjs = Cells[CellStyle -> {"Output"}]
SelectionMove[#, All, Cell]; FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]; & /@ cellObjs;
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  I did think about using `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]`, but was not able to select all input-output groups (and only those).  Is there a way?      (Also, please see Edit #2.)

Comment: @Alan I have extended the answer with working approach. I should warn that it rely upon undocumented details of behavior of `"OpenCloseGroup"`, `"SelectionCloseAllGroups"` and `"SelectionOpenAllGroups"` which can change in future versions of *Mathematica*.