# Close or Open, not OpenClose CellGroups for specific CellStyle

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I am aware of the question

[Close programmatically all cell groups in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6809/close-programmatically-all-cell-groups-in-mathematica)

but I am trying to find out how to close only one kind of `Cells` in a notebook, e.g., only chapters or only sections or only subsection and so on. Any ideas? I know I can search for all, e.g., chapter cells with `Cells[CellStyle->"Chapter"]` and at some point I would have to use `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]` but I can not figure out how to **select** the corresponding cell groups and use them with `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]`. Any suggestions on how to complete the code

```
loccells = Cells[CellStyle->"Chapter"]
(*what I am missing*)
FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]
```

It would be important to leave all other cell types untouched, since the approach

```
nb = SelectedNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook]
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]
```

collapses also figures and other cell types I actually want to leave open. Thank you for your time!

**FINAL EDIT:**
Kuba's last version solved my problem, see his answer and the comments. I still will leave my remarks untouched, just for documentation.

**EDIT 1:**
sorry, may be I was not precise enough in my question. I am interested exactly on the opening/closing behavior you get by double clicking on the cell brackets of a cell group, which is triggered by `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]`. I know I can open and close cells in a different way by changing the value of the attribute `CellOpen->True/False`, but a change in that attribute collapses the cell type and does not close it as I am interested in. If you want to see the difference, please test this palette I created just today based on Kuba's answer in any notebook(s)

```
MyPalette = Manipulate[
   (*** Notebook selection ***)
   , Style["Select notebook"]
   , {nb, Notebooks[], PopupMenu}
   , Delimiter
   (*** Input cells ***)
   , Style["Input cells"]
   , Column[
    {
     Button["Hide inputs", cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Input"]; 
      SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> False] & /@ cells, ImageSize -> 80]
     , Button["Show inputs", cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Input"]; 
      SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> True] & /@ cells, ImageSize -> 80]
     }
    ]
   , Delimiter
   (*** Close types with FrontEndTokenExecute ***)
   , Style["Close cell types"]
   , Column[
    {
     Button["Open/close sections",
      Do[
       SelectionMove[cell, All, Cell];
       FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]
       , {cell, Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Section"]}
       ]
      ]
     , Button["Open/close subsections",
      Do[
       SelectionMove[cell, All, Cell];
       FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]
       , {cell, Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Subsection"]}
       ]
      ]
     , Button["Open/close subsubsections",
      Do[
       SelectionMove[cell, All, Cell];
       FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]
       , {cell, Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Subsubsection"]}
       ]
      ]
     }
    ]
   , Delimiter
   (*** Close types with CellOpen ***)
   , Style["Close cell types with CellOpen"]
   , Column[
    {
     Button["Hide sections", 
      cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Section"]; 
      SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> False] & /@ cells, ImageSize -> 80]
     , Button["Show sections", 
      cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Section"]; 
      SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> True] & /@ cells, ImageSize -> 80]
     }
    ]

   ];

CreatePalette[
 MyPalette
 , WindowTitle -> "Hide and show input code in notebooks"
 , Saveable -> False
 ]
```

If you want to test this palette directly on a formatted notebook with sections and subsection use this small example notebook (just evaluate it with ALT+v+o and you will get the palette with the different options for a selectable notebook)

[Test 1.nb (Google drive link)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HppN1nEJ6KMEVuOEZlMTFhRUk/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT 2:**
Just a remark, not a complain. Kuba's new suggestion is more flexible but something is weird. You can use it first, but then if you close manually a section cell group manually using `WholeCellGroupOpener->True` by clicking on the, e.g., section title having this option available, then the code does NOT OPEN this manually activated cell any more. See this GIF

[image: Manually closed closed do not open any more]

If you want to download this notebook, use this link

[Test 2.nb (Google drive link)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HppN1nEJ6KVnlFcGFCbS0zV2M/view?usp=sharing)

This is not a complain, only a remark, since I am already very happy with both solution and you can still combine Kuba's first suggestion with his second. You can close all open groups with his second suggestion and open all groups with his first. Thanks Kuba!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99176/toggle-close-all-input-cells-in-a-notebook-keeping-output-cells-open/99193#99193

Comment: I disagree in closing the question. The attribute CellOpen->True/False collapses the cell and not the corresponding group. The suggestion of Kuba does almost what I want, it just closes/opens cell as you would get by double clicking on the cell brackets. Sadly, as I see it now, there is no further attribute giving information about a cell being open or closed in the sense of double clicking on the cell brackets. I will edit my question.

Comment: Your questions states: "but I am trying to find out how to close only one kind of Cells in a notebook." The linked answer shows how to do that. Selecting groups of cells, the second part of your question, means possibly selecting more than one cell type. So maybe you need to clarify.

Comment: Reading your edit on my phone it looks like you want to select cell groups based on the cell style of the parent cell. Once the cell group is selected you open or close the group ?

Comment: Yeah, I want to select, e.g., a section and close it, as you would by double clicking on the group cell bracket of the section, which then "hides" all children cells but does nothing to them. In the notebook you then just see the section title. If you want to open it again, you double click again on the cell group bracket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Edit

I've updated the old solution to be more flexible. Now you can choose whether to close or to open a group.

```
openCloseAll[nb_, target_String, to : (Open | Closed)] := Do[
  SelectionMove[cell, All, CellGroup, AutoScroll -> False];
  With[{
    content = Block[
      {$Context = "FrontEnd`", $ContextPath = {"System`"}}, 
      NotebookRead[nb]
    ], 
    from = to /. {Closed -> Open, Open -> Closed}
   }, 
    If[ 
      MatchQ[content, Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell[_, target, ___], __}, from]]], 
      NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[CellGroupData[content[[1, 1]], to]], 
       AutoScroll -> False]
    ]
   ];
  , 
   {cell, Cells[CellStyle -> target]}
]
```

The `Block` is there to help with the problem that not documented options, like `WholeCellGroupOpener` after read/write procedure will get `` $CellContext` `` context and will stop working.

More about this issue in [**Programming scripts to create and modify Styleseets. Problems with Contexts**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102189/5478)

Nevertheless, now you can run e.g.:

```
openCloseAll[EvaluationNotebook[], "Subsection", Closed] (*for closing*)
```

or

```
openCloseAll[EvaluationNotebook[], "Subsection", Open] (*for opening*)
```

---

#### Old

That's easy but tricky, unless I've missed the point :)

```
Do[
 SelectionMove[cell, All, Cell];
 FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"],
 {cell, Cells[CellStyle -> "Subsection"]}
 ]
```

Notice I'm moving to `Cell` not to `CellGroup`, that's because if you have an empty `Subsection` then a `CellGroup` will be the parent `Section` group.

Comment: Thank you, it almost does what I would like to have. Sadly, I was not aware that `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]` will close open groups and will open closed groups. My mistake, I was not precise. Do you know a way to close open groups and leave closed groups closed? Do cells have an attribute open/closed in order to differentiate between them???

Comment: thanks a lot! In combination with your first suggestion I get what I wanted. See the second edit of my question only for a remark on your second suggestion.

Comment: I know, I use both, but still a manually closed cell will not open again, see the gif in the second edit of the question. This is not a complain, I can still make it work using your first suggestion in order to open all of them afterwards.

Comment: @MauricioLobos Ok, fixed, the problem was that we were using `Close` while `Closed` is correct :)

Comment: lol, thank you very much!