# Opening a subgroup Explicitly vs Implicitly

Tags: front-end, cells

Suppose we have a Section, Subsection and Subsubsection cell grouped automatically, as in the gif below.  I can programmatically open the Subsection Cell using the code in the gif.

[image]

If the section cell is closed then the Subsection and subsubsection cells are not visible.  However, when I apply the code, the cells open and are visible.  This is what I mean by opening a group "explicitly".  I do not want this.

Is it possible to open a group and that's all it does?  I do not want to necessarily show it.  I call this opening a group "implicitly".   I know I can programmatically close the Section cell again.  But I have many cell types and large notebooks, with many different levels of subgroups so this method is going to be a difficult puzzle. I'd like an easier method.

Is there some feature that allows me to open a subgroup (and not necessarily see it being opened)?  It seems like this should be a feature as I'm asking for the bare minimum... just to open a group.

Comment: closely related: [Close or Open, not OpenClose CellGroups for specific CellStyle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102573/5478)

Answer (score 1):

Since everything in Mathematica is an expression, all we need to do for these types of operations is to check the output of `NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]]` and see what replacements should be done.

For this problem you can try executing this:

```
NotebookPut[NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]] /. 
  CellGroupData[{Cell[x___, "Subsection", y___], z___}, Closed] :> 
    CellGroupData[{Cell[x, "Subsection", y], z}, Open],InputNotebook[]]
```

Comment: Thank you, however this solution creates a new notebook with the feature requested.  However, I need a solution that does this in the existing notebook.  My notebook involve docked cells and hyperlinks... so its not going to work creating a new notebook.  It seems like there must be a simple way.  Ideas?

Comment: Fixed it. Now it overwrites the current one

Comment: Thank you.  hmmm... it seems to work... however, it's batting about 50% breaking Mathematica forcing me to restart.  Strange.

Comment: If there is a way to do this without creating a new notebook it would help me a lot.  However, if this is the only way... then I'll make do.  Thank you.

Comment: Ideally you should do this in a different notebook and replace the `InputNotebook[]` with the path to the actual notebook. This might fix the problems