# Fold/unfold all groups at given level via keyboard shortcut

Tags: cells, keyboard

The combination `ctrl+'` can be used to fold/unfold a selected group.

Is there a way to fold/unfold all cells at a given nesting level, and possibly also to fold/unfold all groups?
I'm thinking something along the lines of `ctrl+k ctrl+j`, `ctrl+k ctrl+1` and so on, that are used for these kinds of folding actions in Visual Studio Code, Atom, and possibly other editors.

Given that in a Mathematica notebook the "nesting" works different than in a regular code editor (no nesting inside code for one), by "nesting level" I here mean to fold/unfold all chapters, sections, subsections and so on.

*Edit:*
I've just found [this other post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102575/27539) where Kuba gives a function to open/close all groups at a given level. It therefore only remains to find a way to bind this to the appropriate keyboard shortcuts.

I'm however not sure how to use the above mentioned bindings to do this.

Comment: You could iterate the folding process (via the appropriate front-end token) then put that iteration into your KeyEventTranslations.tr

Comment: @b3m2a1 possibly, but my first problem with that is that I cannot find the appropriate front-end token to use. Strangely enough, searching `KeyEventTranslations.tr` for `'` or words related to grouping/folding doesn't give me anything

Comment: That's in MenuSetup.tr (most of the key-events are).

Comment: thanks, found it. So the token seems to be `OpenCloseGroup`. Still I cannot seem to make it work from the front end. Something like `FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken[EvaluationNotebook[], "OpenCloseGroup"]` does nothing

Comment: Try this:
``SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], All, CellGroup];
FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@PreviousCell[], "OpenCloseGroup"]``

Comment: Here's the answer to your update: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6227/38205

Comment: @b3m2a1 do you know if thers is a way to use a sequence of characters for a command? Something like `... KeyEvent["k1", Modifiers -> {Control}] ...` does not work. I'm trying to have a command execute when pressing two characters in succession while `ctrl` is down

Comment: I don't think that's possible (I don't know if even tkinter in python supports that). But post a question about it and maybe you'll get a better answer.